# how to load a flex properties file in to a javascript/jquery singlepage app

Tags: jquery, properties, substitution

I am working on a jquery based single page app and have been asked to reuse a properties localization file that their flex app used. I can use require.js to load them, however how can I use the values to be substitution values in the app?

here is a snippet of what these files look like

```
ERROR_REPORT_FAILED_TITLE=Submit Error
ERROR_REPORT_FAILED_MESSAGE=We have been unable to report your error.
SCREEN_TITLE_BRANCH_SEARCH=Branch Search
SCREEN_LABEL_FIND_BRANCHES=Find Branches
SCREEN_LABEL_BRANCH_NAME=Branch Name
SCREEN_LABEL_SELECT_BRANCH=Select Branch
```

I can't change the files as the flex app will be using them the same time the single page app is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

was able to do this with a get and split on the line break \n and then split on = to break it in to name value pairs